# Expose private internal class size

Tags: c++, enums, compile-time-constant

I need to expose a compile time constant with the size of internal class. To do so I tried next code:

```
#include <cassert>

struct A
{
    //consider Private class as private for this example, just to be able to put the assert like this in main
    class Private{};
    enum { PrivateSize = sizeof(Private) };
};

int main()
{
    //here I have warning on some compilers, signed/unsigned comparison
    assert(A::PrivateSize == sizeof(A::Private));
}
```

My problem is that `PrivateSize` is signed on some compiler and unsigned on others and I get warnings about this when comparing it with signed types. As far as I know `enum`'s underlying type is implementation defined and can't be forced to be `signed` or `unsigned`.

Do you know a way to expose `sizeof(A::Private)` outside `A` as compile time constant, but keeping `Private` class... private? Please note I can't use `constexpr` as the code will be used on some old compilers.

Comment: I assume you can not change A

Comment: @DieterLücking I can change A, but I have to keep internal class private

Comment: You may use `static const unsigned PrivateSize` instead of enum to avoid warning.

Comment: A friend function holding the assert will do it

Answer (score 4):

Following works:

```
struct A
{
    friend int main(int argc, char *argv[]); // For test purpose
private:
    class Private{};
public:
    static const unsigned int PrivateSize = sizeof (Private);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(A::PrivateSize == sizeof(A::Private));
    return 0;
}
```